# LINQ to Entities - Best way to accomplish this?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

OK, I am mostly a LAMP developer so I am new to the entity framework. However, I am familiar with the basics in LINQ and have generated a entity model from my DB. Now here is my requirement:

I have a datagrid on a WinForm that will be refreshed from a data source on a remote server every few seconds as changes to the dataset are made from other sources. Obviously, I'd like to construct a lambda expression to get the right anonymous type to satisfy the columns that needs to be shown in my datagrid. I have done this and here is the result (I'm using a custom datagrid control, btw):

[image]

And my code thus far:

```
Models.dataEntities objDB = new Models.dataEntities();

var vans = from v in objDB.vans
           select v;

gcVans.DataSource = vans;
```

OK, so now I have my basic data set. One problem I had is that the "Status" column will show a calculated string based on several parameters in the data set. I added this to my entities via a partial class. As you can see in the screenshot, this is working correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1.Models {

    public partial class van {

        public string van_status {

            get {

                if (this.is_offline == 1) {

                    return "Offline";

                } else if (this.is_prayer_room == 1) {

                    return "In Prayer Room";

                } else {

                    return "TODO: Create statuses";

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This added property works fine. However, the second I try to project the status in an anonymous type so I can also retrieve the school name, I get an error:

```
Models.dataEntities objDB = new Models.dataEntities();

var vans = from v in objDB.vans
           select new {

               van_name = v.van_name,
               school_name = v.school.school_name,
               capacity = v.capacity,
               phone = v.phone,
               van_status = v.van_status

           };

gcVans.DataSource = vans;
```

[image]

So, I have two questions:

1) If I cannot use computed properties of my partial classes in LINQ projections, how am I supposed to show my computed string in my datagrid?

2) Am I even approaching this correctly? When I resolve #1, how would I refresh this data (ie during a timer fire event)? Would I simply call `objDB.refresh()` and then tell my datagrid to update from the datasource? Does calling that method actually run the lambda expression above or does it load everything from the DB?

Thanks for any assistance with this. Also, if you have any best practices to share that would be awesome! I hope I explained this as thoroughly as you need to provide assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Instead of modifying your EF object with a partial class you could always create your own class that contains your read only property van_status.  The code you've got would be nearly identical:

```
Models.dataEntities objDB = new Models.dataEntities();
gcVans.DataSource = from v in objDB.vans
           select new DisplayVan {
               van_name = v.van_name,
               school_name = v.school.school_name,
               capacity = v.capacity,
               phone = v.phone,
           };
```

The van_status property, since it's read-only, will not need to be specified in the query.

2) I'm more a web developer than a desktop developer so I'll give you my take on how to refresh the grid (it may not be the preferred methodology for fat clients)...

I'm reluctant to trust .Refresh() methods and hope all works to maximal efficiency and work properly.  Instead, encapsulate the code from #1 in a method of your own and invoke it from your timer event firing (or however you choose to implement the periodic refresh).

Comment: Tahbaza - Thank you for clarifying that. I forgot about the ability to project into a custom type. That is amazing. One more question, in that custom type "DisplayVan" do I need to do anything special to that class or will it just be a simple, every-day C# class? (ie do I need to implement anything to make it work?) And, in that class, do I need to define every property or can it somehow inherit the entities properties?

Comment: I would just make it a "POCO" object, just a list of desired properties.  The class doesn't need to inherit from anything.  EF is supposed to have a POCO implementation that has just become (or should soon be) functional but in the meantime I'd just create the 4 required properties as unrelated to the EF object.  Once POCO EF entities are functional and stable I'll be switching to them as well when I have to use EF over NHibernate.

Comment: Thank you, one last question. Can you point me to where I can read more about the status of EF POCO objects?

Comment: These links: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx are outdated but Scott Gu's blog is worth following.  Official MS releases can be browsed here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/tags/codeonly/ but you've touched on the problem with this technology: scattered  examples/documentation to date...  Until it's released and best practices are published why would one use it in production?  Enjoy C#!

Comment: Why not just use an anonymous type?

Answer (score 1):

Another good option would be to create an extension method.

Here is a simple example:

```
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Van van = new Van();
            string status = van.GetStatus();
        }
    }

    public static class VanExtension {
        public static string GetStatus(this Van van) {
            if(van.is_offline == 1) {
                return "Offline";
            }
            else if(van.is_prayer_room == 1) {
                return "In Prayer Room";
            }

            return "TODO:  Create statuses";
        }
    }

    public class Van {
        public int is_offline { get; set; }
        public int is_prayer_room { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- Be sure to put this extension class in the same namespace as the entity class.

Comment: Would I be able to bind a grid column to the GetStatus() method?